# How to get values from Fortran DLL using Python?

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes, intel-fortran

I have Fortran dll(FortDll.dll) similar to;

```
integer function FortAddr(x) bind(c, name="FORTADDR") RESULT(res)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPOR::FortAddr
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
integer(kind=c_int), intent(in) :: x
integer :: y

y = 2*x
res = loc(y)
end function
```

I want to import Fortran data to visualize using python.
And from python, I call it as

```
import ctypes

flib = CDLL('FortDll.dll')
x = c_int(15)
addrx = flib.FORTADDR(byref(x))
val = ctypes.cast(addrx, ctypes.py_object).value
```

But Python script stops at ctypes.cast. How can I get the value in Fortran dll?

Comment: “Stops”. Do you get an error?  Post it.  Probably need to set `flib.FORTADDR.restype` to something like `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)`. If I remember correctly, FORTRAN returns by reference. Then `print(addrx.contents)`

Comment: I followed your instruction but there's nothing to show. "Stops" means no output and it terminates without any message. Also, `addrx.contents` shows no result.

Comment: Can you post a link to the DLL?